# Ender 3 print temperature

Tags: creality-ender-3, pla, temperature, stringing

I've tried different retraction speeds and distances using calibration models, Z-hop, coasting but nothing prevented stringing. Now I tried printing at 230 °C and that seems to do the trick. Even 220 °C gives me strings. The filament is quite new.

Has somebody had a similar experience and could you tell me if something else is wrong maybe?

Comment: Can you add a picture showing the stringing you see? There are several different "types" and seeing which it is can help a lot in diagnosis.

Comment: If increasing temperature helps, I think the most likely cause is wet filament. Even new filament can be wet, even if the manufacturer did everything right, if the distributor/warehouse/shipping handled it poorly. Especially thost numbers - going from 210 to 230 is exactly what I have to do to compensate for wet PLA if I'm too lazy to dry it. I don't get stringing, just other problems, but that's probably because my retraction and travel speeds (45 ms, 400 mm/s) are so high as to not allow time for oozing.

Comment: I think you are right, I will try it with different type of filament.

Comment: You could also just try drying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just needed drying, even though it was brand new. Thnx @R.. GitHub STOP HELPING ICE.